# How to reference kubernetes docker-registry

Tags: kubernetes, cert-manager

I have installed docker-registry on Kubernetes via helm.

I am able to docker push to `docker push 0.0.0.0:5000/<my-container>:v1` using port-forward.

Now how do I reference the images in the registry from a deployment.yaml?

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: <my-container>-deployment-v1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: <my-container>-deployment
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: <my-container>
        image: 0.0.0.0:5000/<my-container>:v1 # <<< ????
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: private-docker-registry-secret
```

This do list my containers:

```
curl -X GET http://0.0.0.0:5000/v2/_catalog
```

I keep getting ***ImagePullBackOff*** when deploying.

I tyied using internal service name and cluster ip address, still not working.

Then tried using secrets:

```
{
  "kind": "Secret",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "running-buffoon-docker-registry-secret",
    "namespace": "default",
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/running-buffoon-docker-registry-secret",
    "uid": "127c93c1-53df-11e9-8ede-a63ad724d5b9",
    "resourceVersion": "216488",
    "creationTimestamp": "2019-03-31T18:01:56Z",
    "labels": {
      "app": "docker-registry",
      "chart": "docker-registry-1.7.0",
      "heritage": "Tiller",
      "release": "running-buffoon"
    }
  },
  "data": {
    "haSharedSecret": "xxx"
  },
  "type": "Opaque"
}
```

And added the secret to to deployment.yaml:

```
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: running-buffoon-docker-registry-secret
```

Then I get:

```
image "x.x.x.x/:<my-container>v1": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://x.x.x.x/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the **cluster-ip** of your local docker registry.

You will find this in the dashboard - just visit the registry pod page and then to the associated `service`. Replace your image spec's `0.0.0.0` with the cluster ip. Also make sure the `port` matches - generally the port exposed by registry service is different from the actual port exposed inside the cluster. If you have authentication set up in your registry, you will need `imagepullsecret` as well.

I have blogged about minikube setup with a local registry - might be helpful. https://amritbera.com/journal/minikube-insecure-registry.html

Comment: Thanks, but still no luck - I updated the question to include using secrets.

Comment: What port does it show in the service? It doesn't have to be 5000. Maybe put the pod cluster IP and port directly and try?